# Most appropriate place for custom Puppet facts - RHEL

Tags: puppet, ruby, facter

I'm not much of a Ruby guy, but found how to list the Ruby load path. Here's what it looks like for me

```
$ ruby -e 'puts $:'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8
/usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.8
/usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby
/usr/lib64/site_ruby/1.8
/usr/lib64/site_ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux
/usr/lib64/site_ruby
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux
```

Some of these directories don't even exist, and frankly, I'd think custom fact *.rb* files would be best placed in a Puppet-ish location, like */etc/puppet/facts* or similar.

Should I go with one of the existing load path locations or create a new one for purposes of Puppet?

Comment: Store them on the server as part of your modules, and let pluginsync put them where they need to go?

Comment: Oh wow, that was pretty straightforward, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best practise is to put any facts and other plugins within modules on the puppet server.  Then use the pluginsync feature on the client.  This lets the puppet client put things in the appropriate location.

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/plugins_in_modules.html

```
{modulepath}
└── {module}
    └── lib
        |── augeas
        │   └── lenses
        ├── facter
        └── puppet
            ├── parser
            │   └── functions
            ├── provider
            |   ├── exec
            |   ├── package
            |   └── etc... (any resource type)
            └── type
```

So a new fact might go into `modules/examplemod/lib/facter/myfact.rb`.

Since `facter-1.7` there's also the possibility to have [external facts](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_facts.html), that can be deployed in `/etc/facter/facts.d` and can be written in any language.

Comment: @dawud, so external facts can't be pushed with pluginsync?

Comment: There's no need to. they are somewhat static resources that reside in every host you want to have a custom fact into.